# ODE: The Lyapunov stability of a set

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, stability-theory

When talking about the Lyapunov stability of a dynamical system, we usually take some point in the domain to test its stability. For example, for the ODE $\dot{x} = -x$, the origin $ x = 0 $ is asymptotically stable. But, I saw a paper about the stability of a dynamical system where the stability is defined for a set rather than a point. They defined the distance
$$
{\rm{dist}}(x,A) = \inf_{y \in A}{\Vert x - y \Vert}
$$
and also defined that a closed set $ A $ is asymptotically stable if there exists a class $ \mathcal{KL} $ function $ \beta $ such that for the solution $ x(t) $,

$$
\forall t \ge t_{0}:~{\rm{dist}}(x(t),A) \le \beta({\rm{dist}}(x_{0},A), t - t_{0} )
$$

where $ t_{0} $ and $ x_{0} $ are the initial time and state, respectively. I think it is a quite reasonable generalization of stability.

I wonder if there are good references to such a definition. Is this a common definition of stability of a dynamical system? If so, I want some representative references (textbook or paper) introducing it.

Comment: What paper did you read?

Comment: @JinraeKim I found the references by myself, and I share them FYI :)

Answer (score 2):

I found some useful references for this topic: the stability of a closed invariant set, or simply, the set stability. The original paper where I encountered the definition is

*Reduction Principles and the Stabilization of Closed Sets for Passive
Systems (2010) by El-Hawwary*

and the set stability and attractivity are defined in it. The definition in OP is my reformulation of the definition in the paper, but honestly, I didn't verify that both are equivalent.

The references for the definition I found so far include

1. [pp. 331-332] Nonlinear Systems (2002) by Khalil
2. Dynamical Systems: Stability Theory and Applications (1967) by Bhatia
3. [Chap. IV] Stability Theory by Liapunov's Second Method (1966) by Yoshizawa
4. [Chap. IV] Methods of A. M. Lyapunov and their Application (1964) by Zubov

You may think the sources are a bit outdated, but I had no difficulty understanding notations and they are actually very well-written books. Yoshizawa's book is the one that I recommend reading.